# SIMD : registers changing value during execution

Tags: c++, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx2

So something strange is happening in my code at the moment, it is about the following register `__m256i local`, assigned during a computation somewhere, as well as `__m256i mask`, which is unrelated to local.

Where running the following :

```
  std::cout << _mm256_extract_epi32 (local, 0) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,1) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,2) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,3) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,4) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,5) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,6) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,7) << std::endl;

  for (int l = 0; l < 8; ++l)
  {
    if (mask[l]) mask[l] = 0; else mask[l] = 1;
  }
  std::cout << _mm256_extract_epi32 (local, 0) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,1) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,2) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,3) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,4) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,5) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,6) << ", " << _mm256_extract_epi32(local,7) << std::endl;`
```

I obtain `519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519, 519` for the first output and `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` for the second, even though they come from the same register. Any idea how something like this could happen ?

Comment: This is not a [mcve] as it lacks definitions for `local` and `mask`, including how those variables get their values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the intent of your for-loop to access the 32-bit words within the 256-bit `mask` vector? That's not the correct way to do that. When you use the subscript operator to access `mask`, the compiler is overrunning the location of the actual `mask` variable in memory, and clobbering the subsequent 7x 256-byte region following it.

If you want to easily access the 32-bit words within `mask`, try declaring it as:

```
union vec8x32_t
{
  __m256i  vector;
  uint32_t words[8];
};

vec8x32_t mask;
```

Then you can do like:

```
// Do some AVX thing with mask:
mask.vector = _mm256_set_epi32(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1);

// Manipulate the components of mask:
for (int l = 0; l < 8; ++l)
{
  if (mask.words[l]) mask.words[l] = 0; else mask.words[l] = 1;
}
```

Comment: OP's code, as presented, won't compile.  If you look at the definition for `__m256i` (it's in `<immintrin.h>`) you'll see that it is already a union and your union is unnecessary.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, that seems to be compiler-dependent. I do see that definition in MSVC 2015, but GCC 7 doesn't provide it, complaining: ``error: request for member ‘m256i_u32’ in ‘mask’, which is of non-class type ‘__m256i {aka __vector(4) long long int}’.``

Comment: Then GCC isn't using the standard Intel headers for those.  Sigh.